# s3.listObjects() data variable returns null

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, serverless

I'm trying to write my first lambda function using the Serverless framework that will copy files from the `texts/` folder to the `target/` folder in an S3 bucket called `s3-trigger-serverless-test`. When calling the `listObjects()` function though, I receive the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'Contents' of null
    at Response.<anonymous> (/var/task/src/handler.js:14:12)
    at Request.<anonymous> (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:364:18)
    at Request.callListeners (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:105:20)
    at Request.emit (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:77:10)
    at Request.emit (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:683:14)
    at Request.transition (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:22:10)
    at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12)
    at /var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:26:10
    at Request.<anonymous> (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:38:9)
    at Request.<anonymous> (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:685:12)
```

handler.js:

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var bucketName = 's3-trigger-serverless-test';
var oldPrefix = 'texts/';
var s3 = new AWS.S3({params: {Bucket: bucketName}});

module.exports.copyFilesToS3 = (event, context, callback) =>  {
    s3.listObjects({Bucket: bucketName, Prefix: oldPrefix}, function(err, data) {
        if (data.Contents.length) {           // this line results in the error above
```

serverless.yml:

```
functions:
  copyFilesToS3:
    handler: src/handler.copyFilesToS3
    events:
      - s3: 
          bucket: s3-trigger-serverless-test
          event: s3:ObjectCreated:*
          rules:
            - prefix: 'texts/'
```

The aws-sdk version is up-to-date, as suggested by another stackoverflow answer. I'm thinking it might be because the Bucket and Prefix parameters I passed into `listObjects()` didn't return any data from the S3 bucket, but I've played around with other parameters and bucket settings, and I haven't been able to come up with a solution yet.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your first test inside the callback should be `if(err) { ...`.  Ignoring the error handed to you is never a good idea.

Comment: Thank you, you're absolutely right. ````err```` returned an Access Denied error, so I edited the bucket policies to allow my IAM user to access the bucket, and now my lambda compiles correctly. Thanks for the tip!